# Overwrite Vim theme color scheme

Tags: colorscheme

How can I change the color scheme of an installed Theme?

I currently have gruvbox installed and I would like to change the color of node.js keyword 'import' from aqua to orange.

To no avail, I have edited the gruvbox.vim file to include:

```
hi! link javascriptImport GruvboxOrange
```

instead of:

```
hi! link javascriptImport GruvboxAqua
```

Comment: Does it work if you put the `hi! link javascriptImport GruvboxOrange` at the end of your `.vimrc` instead? What if you run it directly from the vim command line?

Comment: Have you installed any additional vim files to provide syntax highlighting for node.js?  Check the value of `:set filetype`.

Comment: hi! link javascriptImport GruvboxOrange at the end of my .vimrc file and directly in the command line have no effect

Comment: @JigglyNaga this appears to be it. After disabling all of the plugins except gruvbox the modified scheme became visible.